# Matrix: Not able to add more than 50 rows

Tags: matrix

I am using EE v2.5.5 and Matrix v2.5.3.

In Matrix, I'm able to add up to 50 rows without problems. When I add more than 50 rows and click the Submit button, I am returned to the entry edit form again.

Is there a 50 row limit on Matrix fields?

Answer (score 1):

You may already be aware of this, but you could try to switch over to Grid, the native built-in EE fieldtype. They do the same job with very little difference. And Grid might not have that 50 entry limit.

- [Introducing Grid, New in ExpressionEngine 2.7 - EllisLabs](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/introducing-grid-new-in-expressionengine-2.7)
- [Grid Field - ExpressionEngine User Guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/grid.html)